# Second variation positive definite but not weak local minimum?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider a functional $J \colon S \to \mathbb{R}$ where $S \subseteq C^2[a,b]$. Let $J(y) = \int_a^b f(x,y,y') \, dx$, let $y$ be an extremal (solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation) for $J$, and suppose the second variation of $J$ at $y$ is positive definite. Does it follow that $J$ has a weak local minimum at $y$, where $weak$ means *with respect to the norm*
$$||y||_1 = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |y(x)| + \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |y'(x)|?$$

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to assume that $y$ is an inner point of $S$ and that there's some
$\varepsilon >0$ so that in the ball $B_{\varepsilon} ( y ) \subset S$ one has
$\delta^{2} J ( y;v ) >0$ for every $v \in B_{\varepsilon} ( y )$.

Fix some $v \in B_{\varepsilon} ( y )$ and define $\varphi ( t ) := y+t (
v-y )$ for $t \in [ 0,1 ]$. Then obviously $\varphi ( t ) \in B_{\varepsilon}
( y )$ for all $t$ and $\delta^{2} J ( \varphi ( t ) ;v-y ) >0$ too. Now define the new functional $I ( t ) := J ( \varphi ( t ) )$. This is
twice differentiable if $J$ is and one has $I' ( t ) = \delta J ( \varphi ( t
) ,v-y )$ and $I'' ( t ) = \delta^{2} J ( \varphi ( t ) ;v-y ) >0$. Therefore,
for some $\tau \in [ 0,1 ]$:

$$ I ( 1 ) -I ( 0 ) =I' ( 0 ) + \frac{1}{2} I'' ( \tau ) $$
and the first term is zero because $I' ( 0 ) = \delta I ( u,v-y )$ and the
second is positive. This means

$$ J ( v ) -J ( y ) >0, $$

or: $y$ is a strict local minimizer of $J$.